# Does caching a single EF 6 DBContext in HTTP cause concerns?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, caching, httpcontext

I am working on a project where we are conflicted about whether or not to cache a EF 6 DBContext in the HTTP request.

For each HTTP request, we instantiate multiple classes, and we might call multiple methods on each on of them.

Is one DBContext instance per class instance best, or is it okay to cache a single Dbcontext in the HTTPContext.Cache ?

Other factors:

- I am leaning towards one DBContext per class, but others are concerned of the cost for "new DBContext"
- We do not use a IoC/DI-container
- We are not doing intentional Async operations.
- Some of the related answers are from 2010, and I want to make sure those are relevant

Answer (score 3):

Don't cache context instances between requests. They are designed to be used in a small scope and disposed. A cached context will "leak" (or rather, consume more and more) memory as it accumulates all the change-tracking data from all of your application's queries and commits.

> [When working with Web applications, use a context instance per request.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj729737.aspx)

The same document also mentions:

> The context is not thread safe. You can still create a multithreaded application as long as an instance of the same entity class is not tracked by multiple contexts at the same time.

Which completely precludes a shared context because requests are served by the *many* threads of the ThreadPool.

Here's how you might implement a per-request shared context in an MVC app:

Global.asax:

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    public const string dbcontext = "Db.Context";

    public MvcApplication()
    {
        BeginRequest += MvcApplication_BeginRequest;
        EndRequest += MvcApplication_EndRequest;
    }
    void MvcApplication_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Items[dbcontext] = new BlahContext();
    }
    void MvcApplication_EndRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var ctx = HttpContext.Current.Items[dbcontext] as BlahContext;
        if (ctx != null)
            try
            {
                (ctx as IDisposable).Dispose();

            }
            catch (ObjectDisposedException)
            {
                //yum
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  Regarding to the HTTPContext.Cache - is the lifetime per web request?

Comment: What sense would a cache have that has a liftime of a web request? Seriously? And what does the documnetaiton say?

Comment: No, that cache is designed for items that out-live the request scope. A per-request collection that you *could* use is `HttpContext.Current.Items`. Personally, I'd just use a context per logical operation and not cache anything at all. I think that was the intention in its design.

Comment: Thanks Spender. Appreciate the feedback.